# Subversion tagging fails using Bamboo

Tags: svn, tags, bamboo

I am trying to create a tag in the svn after building in Bamboo. I am using a VCS Tagging task. I created the directory in the proper location but I am getting the following error.

When I added the source repository I didn't have to set any user/password, I only selected "FishEye Subversion". Because we use JIRA and SVN and Bamboo hosted by attlassian it seems to ba "all conected" so I didn't need to do it. But now it seems that Bamboo user (or whatever user Bambo uses to get the code changes) doen't have permission to commit changes.

How can I fix this? How does bambo authenticate with the SVN server and how can I change that so it can commit and create the tags?

```
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36    Error occurred while running Task 'Tagged by Bamboo'. This build will fail. Caused by: 
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36    com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskException: Exception when tagging repository
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs.task.VcsTaggingTask.execute(VcsTaggingTask.java:57)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.executeTasks(TaskExecutorImpl.java:188)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.execute(TaskExecutorImpl.java:94)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.tasks.ExecuteBuildTask.call(ExecuteBuildTask.java:87)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.build(DefaultBuildAgent.java:206)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.waitAndPerformBuild(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:103)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent$1.run(DefaultBuildAgent.java:111)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:52)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36    Caused by: com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.RepositoryException: Error while creating tag
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.createTag(SvnRepository.java:1918)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs.task.VcsTaggingTask.execute(VcsTaggingTask.java:52)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        ... 8 more
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36    Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36    svn: E170001: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/!svn/act/119a900a-3f01-0010-8d97-3313e23e6ce8': 403 Forbidden (https://xxxxx)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.copyReposToRepos(SVNCopyDriver.java:378)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.setupCopy(SVNCopyDriver.java:627)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNCopyClient16.doCopy(SVNCopyClient16.java:440)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:65)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:23)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnRemoteCopy.run(SvnRemoteCopy.java:227)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient.doCopy(SVNCopyClient.java:480)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.copyRepository(SvnRepository.java:1876)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        at com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.createTag(SvnRepository.java:1914)
error   03-Jun-2013 16:03:36        ... 9 mor
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed repository type to Subversion (it was FishEye) and it worked.